# Testing if JS method throws RangeError with QUnit

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, assert, qunit, throws

I made some Javascript unit tests with QUnit library, then I want to test if method throws RangeError. It has be done in this way:

```
QUnit.test("Resolve slide animation from left", function( assert ) {
var myOwnCreator = new MyOwnCreator();
assert.equal(myOwnCreator.resolveAnimationType("slideSide", "show", "left"),
  "slide-left-in");
assert.equal(myOwnCreator.resolveAnimationType("slideSide", "hide", "left"),
  "slide-left-out");
assert.throws(myOwnCreator.resolveAnimationType("slideSide", "hide"), 
  new RangeError(),
  " If animation type is 'slideSide', you have to provide correct direction" 
  + "to identify animation properly, direction cannot be 'undefined'");
});
```

First and second test passed, because animation classes resolved by function (,,slide-...") were ok. But third test died:

```
Died on test #3     at file...
```

Because it throws RangeError. It's ok that it throws RangeError, but I don't understand how I can catch it in unit test, to get ,,ok" information. If I understand QUnit documentation: [QUnit throws documentation](http://api.qunitjs.com/throws/)

I do everything ok: I pass function which throws Error, instance of expected Error and expected message. I anybody would decide to help me, I will be very happy - thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an answer on my own. Instead calling function:

```
assert.throws(myOwnCreator.resolveAnimationType("slideSide", "hide"), 
  new RangeError()....
```

I should pass to assert.throws() function which call my function, like this:

```
assert.throws(function(){
    myOwnCreator.resolveAnimationType("slideSide", "hide");
  }, 
  new RangeError(--message which function should throw in error--)...
```

Comment: That's it! Glad you found it.