# QUnit testing strategy for object with init function that could throw

Tags: google-apps-script, qunit

I am using [`QUnit`](https://github.com/simula-innovation/qunit/tree/gas/gas) for Google Apps Script, and am attempting unit-testing on my code base, namely on this custom spreadsheet helper function I wrote:

```
function DataStoreHelper() {
  this.argNames = arguments;    // TODO: check type of arguments
  this.argIndices = new Array(this.argNames.length);
  /* takes an array of column names and assigns the indices where they can be found, to this.argIndices
   */
  this.sortColumns = function (columnNames) { 
    // for each argument name ...
    for (var j in this.argNames)
    {
        var k = 0; 
      // ... sift thru the column names ...
      for (k in columnNames) {
          // ... to find the column name that contains the argument name ...
        if (columnNames[k].toLowerCase().indexOf(this.argNames[j]) !== -1) break;
        else if (k == columnNames.length - 1) k = -1;

      }
      // if we found it, we write it to this.argIndices
      if (k > -1) this.argIndices[j] = k;
      // otherwise, we have spreadsheet error.
      else throw new Error('Spreadsheet is missing column for constructor argument: ' + this.argNames[j]);
      Logger.log('this.argNames[%s] == %s\tthis.argIndices[%s] == %s\n',
        j, 
        this.argNames[j],
        j,
        this.argIndices[j])
    }
  }
}
// static const strings
DataStoreHelper.POTHOLE_NUMBER  = 'number';
DataStoreHelper.LATITUDE        = 'latitude';
DataStoreHelper.LONGITUDE       = 'longitude';
DataStoreHelper.ADDRESS         = 'address';
DataStoreHelper.SURFACE_AREA    = 'area';
DataStoreHelper.BAGS            = 'bags';
DataStoreHelper.SNAPPED_TO_ROAD = 'snappedtoroad';
DataStoreHelper.FILLED          = 'filled';
DataStoreHelper.IMAGE_URL       = 'imageurl';
```

Note, the `sortColumns` throws exception iff it's looking for keyword in the spreadsheet columns that doesn't exist.

I begin writing my unit-testing code:

```
function testDataStoreHelper() {
    // construct some DataStoreHelpers....
    /* NOTE: these should be mocks, as we are trying to test behaviour. Find out how to create mock objects */
    var customDataHelper  = new DataStoreHelper(DataStoreHelper.ADDRESS,
            DataStoreHelper.LATITUDE,
            DataStoreHelper.LONGITUDE,
            DataStoreHelper.FILLED,
            'statechange');
    var testData = {};
    module('testing PotholeDataHelper', {
        setup: function() { 
            // test setup logic goes here....
            testData = tests.DUMMY_DATA;
            testData.noLatLng = [testData.dataRow[0],
                 testData.dataRow[4]   
            ];
            // invoke helper setup here, using testData ... 
            customDataHelper.sortColumns(testData.titleRow);
        }
    })
    test("attempting to map a keyword in a spreadsheet that doesn't have a corresponding column", function(assert) { 
        assert.ok(customDataHelper.argIndices.filter(function(value) { return value === -1; }).length,
            "Somehow, there's one or more mapped keywords that shouldn't be in the spreadsheet");
    })
}
```

As expected for this naive approach, the test(s) fail because exception was thrown in the `setup` callback. How best to test code like this, where the initialization function could throw?

Comment: Have you tried the [`throws` method](http://api.qunitjs.com/assert/throws)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing if JS method throws RangeError with QUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439824/testing-if-js-method-throws-rangeerror-with-qunit)

Comment: Does that go inside the `setup` callback?

Comment: Nope, you use it instead of `assert.ok`